# No DispalyPort option in audio output device menu, Nvidia Drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia, sound, displayport

I can't get my DisplayPort-connected monitor (AW2518HF, external speakers connected) to show up on this drop-down menu:
[Settings > Sound > Output > Output Device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGSxY.png).

I've opened Nvidia X Server Settings and [can assure that DP Audio is enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPpxC.png). Additionally, I booted Windows 7 and was able to select it and play sound just fine.

I'm using a GTX 750 (EVGA; they added a DP port in their version) with the 418 driver installed from Software & Updates on Ubuntu 19.04.

Here's `aplay -l`

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC887-VD Analog [ALC887-VD Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was fixed with the new NVidia drivers (435) that came with Ubuntu 19.10